# How to get Drainage Divide and Streams from DTM

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem

Does anyone know how you can get a map like this attached, having the digital terrain model?

I'm sorry, but I do not know what is the exact technical term in English for them. 
**I hope you understand from the images.**
(maybe drainage divide, water divide, divide, ridgeline, watershed, water parting)
My professor called it *compluvium and impluvium*. But another professor colled it 
*articulation of the morphological type of the soil*.
*(in the Italian language: Carta dei compluvi e displuvi / Articolazione morfologica terreno )*

Thanks in advance for the answers

[image]
[image: carta compluvi e displuvi]
[image: carta morfologica del terreno]

Comment: In QGIS, under the Processing menu, you will find modules in Saga->Terrain Analysis-Hydrology, and also under GRASS->Raster->r.watershed

Answer (score 8):

I realize that this question was asked quite some time ago but there was no other answer provided so I thought I'd add something. The drainage network can be derived from a digital elevation model (DEM) using a threshold flow-accumulation raster. Please take a look at my answer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113634/how-to-extract-drainage-line-network-from-grass-gis-and-qgis/113645#113645) more recent question for details on that process. As for extracting a network of ridge lines, I would suggest using a terrain index called Branch Length, which can be thought of as the compliment of upslope area (flow accumulation) and is perfectly suited to mapping ridge line networks. A paper describing the way branch length is calculated can be found [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13658816.2012.705289#.VBM5bi5dU8w), a basic description can be found [here](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/BranchLength.html), and a tool which I have developed for calculating it can be found in the free and open-source GIS Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml). A ridge network can be derived from a branch length raster in the same way as a drainage network is derived from a flow-accumulation raster, specifically by applying a threshold, usually using a Raster Calculator type operation.

[image]

Note: In the above image, the red network corresponds with ridge lines while the blue network corresponds with valley bottoms (i.e. the channel network). Also, the line networks are raster, but can be vectorized if map overlay is desired.

Another common approach for creating a ridge line network from a DEM is to inverse the DEM by multiplying it by -1 and performing the same type of flow accumulation thresholding that is used for stream network mapping. This is the approach used in the LandMapR software created by R.A. MacMillan. My only concern with this approach is that it requires care in how you remove topographic depressions (actually peaks) from the inverse DEM.