# Creating Stream Order with using thresholding

Tags: arc-hydro, stream-order

While creating stream network, I implement a thresholding. All cells's value is "1". Later, while creating stream segments, Do I use the second thresholding for separating link to segments ?

Answer (score 3):

To create the raster stream network you first threshold a flow accumulation raster, likely using the Raster Calculator or the **Con** tool. You're right that this will create a Boolean streams map of 1's and 0's. To break the streams raster into the various stream segments (links or tributaries) you would use the **Stream Link** tool using the same streams raster generated from the first thresholding as the input. The **Stream Order** tool will also take the same raster stream network derived from the first thresholding operation. So, for any stream network analysis that you perform on a DEM-derived stream network, once you've settled on the the threshold using the techniques described in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115163/create-stream-network-using-arcgis/115174#115174) answer, you don't change the threshold for subsequent analysis operations.

Answer (score 0):

To separate into segments, use the [stream link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000056000000.htm) tool